# How to add DOM element where where the inline script is located

Tags: javascript

How can I add a DOM element at the location of the script?

I know that I can add a div with an ID somewhere and manipulate it using JS, but I want to automatically paste this script multiple places on my web page using WordPress shortcodes. Therefore, the script must know its location and be able to add a DOM element where the script tag is.

```
<div class="example-parent">
    <script>
        var funcThatNeedsADivToAttachOnto = function () {
            //...
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            // Need some code here to add div where this script is locate

            funcThatNeedsADivToAttachOnto();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Want a new div right about here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.currentScript` will give you the `<script>` tag that is currently running, so you can reference that and then use `insertAdjacentElement`:

```html
<div class="example-parent">
    <script>
        (() => {
            // Use an IIFE so that the "script" variable does not pollute the global object
            const script = document.currentScript;
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
                const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.textContent = 'new div';
                script.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newDiv);
                console.log(document.querySelector('.example-parent').innerHTML);
            });
        })();
    </script>
    <!-- Want a new div right about here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, I just had to convert the code to old-style JavaScript because that's what I need.